# Stop my phone from messaging "Good morning" and "Good afternoon" and "You have a new memory" to me

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I'm not the target Apple user and use my iPhone in a limited way. I also have a hard time understanding when computers do things I didn't tell them to do (that's just me, again not the target Apple user).

Why would Photos suddenly decide to say "Good afternoon" to me? (see also [Photos - "You have a new memory"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/326615))

I don't remember typing Search, but this search screen suddenly appeared when I wasn't looking. Could its sudden appearance be related to the "Good afternoon" message?

How can I stop things like "Good afternoon" and "You have a new memory" from appearing, so I can at least have the illusion that I'm in control of my device :-)

(iPhone 6, upgraded from *ancient* to iOS 12.4.5 somewhat recently)

---

[image: screenshot of creepy pointless message from my phone]

[image: screenshot of creepy pointless message from my phone]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered an slr?

Comment: @SolarMike all the time! When they get below 1 cm thick let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Good Afternoon” is an example of “Siri Suggestions” and they can be turned off in Settings under “Siri & Search”.

The feature’s goal is to surface content/actions that it thinks will be useful to you in that moment.

Possibly this will get more useful over time, given that your previous OS may have not been recording how you use your phone.

[image]

—-

To turn off notifications about suggested Memories in Photos, visit Settings - Notifications - Photos - Memories:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty sure Siri will be unhappy with how I use my phone and suggest that I download more content and take more selfies, but oh well :-) So was Siri suggesting that I have a good afternoon? I don't understand the point of that blurb. Why today?

Comment: Do you often look through your photos in the afternoon (“Good afternoon! Do you want to look at your photos? Based on my models, I think you may want to at this moment”)? Maybe it’s just taking a shot in the dark to see what you click on? I can only speculate on their AI/ML.

Comment: I hardly ever use the phone to look at images. Mostly I'm at my laptop, I'd prefer to run my phone completely through the laptop whenever connected. (random [example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/382232)). The phone seems to be full of assumptions that I'm a target Apple user, uhoh! - So the phone generates messages for which the meaning can not be determined? Really? Yikes!

Comment: The question you link to is literally about photos. I think Siri was right to think you may want to look at photos, don’t you? I appreciate the concise messaging, but you can certainly share your feedback with Apple.

Comment: I'm not sure your point about the linked question. I often include links to other posts for context, and I can't parse the rest at all. I'm hoping an answer to my posted question will explain why the "Good afternoon" message was generated, and how I can stop it. Presumably I can stop it with one of those buttons, and perhaps another user will explain the message's purpose, if there is one.

Comment: My point is that you recently took/looked at photos on your Apple devices, as evidenced by the linked question - so it makes sense to suggest the Photos app. Regarding the messaging, it’s literally just wishing you a good afternoon while it suggests the photos app.

Comment: So something like "Would you like to stop what you are doing and use the Photos app now? I think you might, so I've found some nice pictures you might want to look at" perhaps? Okay I'm getting the idea. I linked to the photos question as context that some readers may appreciate; the "you have a new memory" is one of the messages that I've asked about turning off, the linked question provides background information for that message for readers who don't know what it is. I use images a lot, but as far as *looking at them* as a stand-alone activity it's pretty rare.

Comment: Updated answer to explain how to stop getting notifications for memories. iOS is pretty configurable btw, if you dig around a bit (addressing your desire to control what you see).

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is indeed and I love it. My problem is that I'm not a normal user and unfamiliar with what it does, so there are a lot of controls whose functions are obvious to most users and simultaneously cryptic to me. If I communicated with Siri (which I won't) I'd say "It's not you, it's me." or similar.

Comment: This morning Photos wished me a good morning, so I promptly implemented all your answer, *thanks!* I have a lot of very good memories but also several very sad ones, and the last thing I need is a little box yanking my chain telling me that I "have memories" I'm walking knee-deep through my memories 24/7 :-|